# Complex XML to objects

Tags: c#

I have a very large, complex XML file and I wish to extract every element value to an object I already created. I have tried WCF DataContractSerializer and plain XmlSerializer which both were very problematic.

Other than using the above methods to parse my XML and assign to objects, can someone please recommend the easiest way to to achieve the above?

I was considering just using XDocument.

My ultimate goal is to take the values from the object and serialize to a new XML.

Here was my original post
[XML deserialization to object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506535/xml-deserialization-to-object-error)

Comment: a sample of the xml as well as the classes you created to hold the data would be useful

Comment: `which both were very problematic` How?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? What is this "object" you've created?

Comment: I had used xsd to generate the object. I do not want to post the content of the object here

Comment: What errors/problems are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506535/xml-deserialization-to-object-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataContractSerializer and XmlSerializer can only hydrate XML into an object that you already have. Namely, they only work if you start with object of type X, serialize it, and then deserialize it back into type X. Generally, you use them if you are consuming a service that publishes a data contract, or if you are the one serializing the data yourself. Note that I said they serialize the entire object. That goes beyond just the data and includes the structure and types that the data fits into.

Since it's not apparently a serialized object, you are on the right track with building your own object and using XDocument to pick it apart.

Answer (score 4):

I typically use [Microsoft's XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) (XSD.EXE) in two steps to generate the classes that could be deserialized from an arbitrary XML document:

Step 1:

```
xsd file.xml [/outputdir:directory]
```

generates an XSD file that corresponds to your XML file

Step 2:

```
xsd file.xsd /classes [/namespace:namespace] [/outputdir:directory]
```

generates the class(es) that could be deserialized using the schema created in Step 1.

From there you could either use the object as-is or map the object properties to your class's properties.

Comment: Good one. I'd completely forgotten about that tool.

Comment: I have already generated the object from xsd in my initial attempt to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

Use `XmlReader`  or `XmlTextReader`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx

XmlReader or XmlTextReader does not load the whole XML into memory, so it will be helpful for you to parse a such big XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had great success with the XmlSerializer class and the attribute and classes in the System.Xml.Serialization namespace.

When I've had complex XML data I needed to deserialize, or read into an object, I've always gone the other way first. That is first, instantiate the .NET object, and then serialize it out. Then I would slowly and incrementally add attributes to the .NET object to control how I want it to be serialized out. 
Anyways the classes in the [System.Xml.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx) namespace will give you complete control over how to serialize objects. You can serialize a member variable as an attribute or an element. You can serialize arrays of objects, you can even ignore member variables as well. You can change the names of xml elements to be different from the member variable names... I mean it is very powerful.

But anyways, the trick is go backwards. Make the .NET object first, and then start serializing to XML bit by bit. Once you get it how you like it, than it automatically can be deserialized very easily.

So a custom type can be serialized / deserialized like this:

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.google.com",
     ElementName = "BuildServicOptions",
     DataType = "string",
     IsNullable = true)]
public class Options {...}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<BuildServiceOptions ....>
</BuildServiceOptions>
```

Arrays can be serialized like this:

```
[XmlArray("EmailNotifications")]
[XmlArrayItem("email")]
public string[] EmailNotifications;
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<EmailNotifications>
<email>Peter@foo.com</email>
<email>James@foo.com</email>
<email>John@foo.com</email>
</EmailNotifications>
```

Member variables can be ignored like this:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string ServerProjectDir;
```

Member variables can be serialized as Attributes

```
[XmlAttribute("Name")]
public string ProjectName;
```

If you have a custom data-type that is a member variable, well, it's easy: Just add serialization attributes to that class. In fact any class that needs to be written out to the XML file should have attributes on the class definition too.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Here was my original post with the issue I experienced using xml serializer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506535/xml-deserialization-to-object-error